# How to filter dropdown from ajax to display checkbox with the name on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox, drop-down-menu

How can i filter drop down list that when i select the type it shows the type that on ajax response in the checkbox of the name

This is the code for html

```css
fieldset.Field {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.checkbox {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.checkbox li input {
  margin-right: .25em;
}

.container-body ul.checkbox li {
  float: left;
  min-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container position">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="recyclable-type" class="col-form-label"> <b>Recyclable Type:</b> </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select id="recyclable-type" name="recyclable-type" class=" custom-select col-4">
      <option selected value="">All</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-body ">
  <fieldset class="Field">
    <ul id="checkbox" class="checkbox">
  </fieldset>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the code for ajax where i call my drop down and checkbox for type and name

```
$.ajax({
                // The url that you're going to post
                /*

                This is the url that you're going to put to call the
                backend api,
                in this case, it's
                https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8090/api/get (production env)

                */
                url:"https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8090/api/get",
                // The HTTP method that you're planning to use
                // i.e. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
                // In this case it's a get method, so we'll use GET
                method:"GET",
                // In this case, we are going to use headers as
                headers:{
                    // The query you're planning to call
                    // i.e. <query> can be UserGet(0), RecyclableGet(0), etc.
                    query:"RecyclableTypeGet()",
                    // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
                    apikey:sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
                },
                success:function(data,textStatus,xhr) {
                    // console.log(data);
                    for (let i = 0;i<data.length;i++) {
                        $("#recyclable-type").append(
                            `
                            <option val="${data[i]["RecyclableType"]}">${data[i]["RecyclableType"]}</option>
                            `
                        );
                        // can also use this way
                        // $("#select-recyclables").append(
                        //  `
                        //  <option val="${data[i]["RecyclableType"]}">${data[i]["RecyclableType"]}</option>
                        //  `
                        // );
                    }
                },
                error:function(xhr,textStatus,err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });


            $.ajax( {
            url: 'https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8090/api/get',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers:{
                query: "RecyclableGet(0)",
                // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
                apikey: sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
            },
            success: function(data) {
            //console.log(data);
            var html='';
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                html +='<input type="checkbox" name="recyclable_id[]" value="'+value.RecyclableID+'"><label style="padding-left: 10px;">'+value.Name+'</label><br>';
                //console.log(value)
            });
            $('#checkbox').html(html);

            }
        });
```

This is how my ajax response look like

```
[
    {
        "RecyclableID": 1,
        "Name": "recyclable",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 3,
        "Name": "test recyclable 2",
        "RecyclableType": "WASTE"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 129,
        "Name": "test recyclable 4",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 131,
        "Name": "test recyclable 6",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 132,
        "Name": "test recyclable 7",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 133,
        "Name": "test recyclable 8",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 134,
        "Name": "test recyclable 34",
        "RecyclableType": "WASTE"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 138,
        "Name": "recyclable thing",
        "RecyclableType": "WASTE"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 139,
        "Name": "recyclable thing 2",
        "RecyclableType": "Ewaste"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 153,
        "Name": "test recyclable 10",
        "RecyclableType": "Other"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 154,
        "Name": "test recyclable 11",
        "RecyclableType": "Ewaste"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 155,
        "Name": "test recyclable 123",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type 2"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 159,
        "Name": "some recyclable name",
        "RecyclableType": "CC"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 161,
        "Name": "some recyclable name 2",
        "RecyclableType": "Ewaste"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 162,
        "Name": "recyclable 2",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type 2"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 165,
        "Name": "test recyclable 15",
        "RecyclableType": "WASTE"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 166,
        "Name": "test recyclable 18",
        "RecyclableType": "testing type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 167,
        "Name": "some recyclable name 23",
        "RecyclableType": "Ewaster"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 168,
        "Name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 169,
        "Name": "Copper",
        "RecyclableType": "WASTE"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 170,
        "Name": "Choking Bar",
        "RecyclableType": "Ewaste"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 171,
        "Name": "Cabinet",
        "RecyclableType": "Other"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 172,
        "Name": "Cash Box",
        "RecyclableType": "WASTE"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 173,
        "Name": "Copper Telephone Cable",
        "RecyclableType": "Other"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 174,
        "Name": "Rope",
        "RecyclableType": "CC"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 175,
        "Name": "Silver",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    }
]
```

This is how example image of the website look like when i have call the ajax
[image]

This is my current html website look like
[image]

Now i would wan that if the type is selected it display the name to whatever the type it has in the ajax response how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add a **data-type** attribute when you create your checkbox. So change your code as follow

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var type = value.RecyclableType;
    html +='<li data-type="'+ type + '"><input type="checkbox" name="recyclable_id[]" value="'+value.RecyclableID+'"><label style="padding-left: 10px;">'+value.Name+'</label><br></li>';
});
```

Then bind a change event on your dropdown so you can filter your checkbox onchange

```
 $("#checkbox").change(function(){
        var type = $(this).value;
        // hide all checkbox
        $(this).find("li").hide();
        
        //show only checkbox having the  data-type attribute
        $(this).find("li[data-type='" + type + "']").show();      
        
})
```

Comment: //show only checkbox having the  data-type attribute
        $(this).find("div[data-type='" + type + "']").show(); 

Hi i have try this but the change event not working when i try to select it didnt display anything

The value for console.log(type) did display my type

Comment: @Flow sorry i have have used div instead of input in the selector. I have upadted the code. Can you try again?

Comment: hi i have changed it still nth happen no error was given also 

I have change my input field to <li><input> 

And 
<div class="container-body ">
                                    <fieldset class="Field">
                                    <ul id="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                                    </fieldset>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

Does this affect the find input thing ?

Comment: @Flow I have updated the code: change the binding of the change event to the #checkbox, and I put the data-type attribute on the li instead of putting on the input. Can you test it again?

Comment: hi is not changing when click on the drop down still even with the li

Comment: @Flow can you update your code i can test it ?

Comment: not sure how u can test it as there a api token for me i can try put fake data but my friend have help me make the code work using your code as some code wasnt correct in calling

Answer (score 0):

My friend have help me to figure out here the answer

```
     $("#recyclable-type").change(function(){
    var type = $(this).val();

    //show only checkbox having the  data-type attribute
    if ($(this).val()!="" && $(this).val()!=null) {
        // hide all checkbox
        $("#checkbox").find("li").hide();

        // filters by recyclable type
        $("#checkbox").find("li[data-type='" + type + "']").show();
    } else {
        $("#checkbox").find("li").show();
    }
        // console.log($(this).find("li[data-type='" + type + "']"));
    })
```